# RSpec + Capybara: redirect_to external page sends me back to root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a feature test to check whether going to a certain path would redirect the user to an external website.

To disallow external connections in my tests, I have the following in my **spec_helper.rb**:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

my spec does something like:

```
it 'redirects safely' do
  visit "/some/route"

  expect(page).not_to have_content 'MyWebsite'
end
```

In my ApplicationController I have a `before_action` that should redirect externally based on a condition:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :redirect_to_external_website, if: :unsupported_path

  private

  def redirect_to_external_website
    redirect_to 'https://some.other.website'
  end

  def unsupported_path
    # Some conditions
  end 
end
```

The redirect works as expected in development.

When I run the spec, however, I can see there are two redirects occurring (the `redirect_to_external_website` method gets hit twice I think) and then it goes back to my root path.

Any idea what I may be doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't specify what driver you are using with Capybara - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers - I assume you're using the default rack_test driver.

The rack_test driver doesn't support requests to external urls (the domain info is just ignored and all paths are routed directly to the AUT) so your test isn't actually testing what you think it is and `redirect_to 'https://some.other.website'` is actually just redirecting to `/` in your local app (because the rack_test driver sees 'https://some.other.website/' , ignores all the domain stuff and just treats it as '/' in your app under test).

If you happen to be using one of the other drivers Capybara supports that does support external URLs (selenium, poltergeist, capybara-webkit, etc.) then your WebMock isn't doing what you think it is, because it only controls requests your AUT makes, it doesn't control anything the "browsers" used by those drivers do so they would be free to make requests to outside URLs.

The functionality you are attepting to test is much more suited to be tested through a request spec - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec - than through a feature/system spec.

Comment: Brilliant, this worked. I had a directive in my routes file that was redirecting on `/` which explains the double redirect I was noticing. Moving this into a request spec allows the test logic to flow correctly! Thanks so much